# Limits of applock in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking, limits

Microsoft SQL Server offers an arbitrary application-defined locking mechanism through the [sp-getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) command and related commands.

The key, or `resource_name`, is specified as a string, a varchar 255. But the documentation also mentions that the key/name is hashed.

So that leads me to wonder:

- What kind of hashing function is used?
- How well-distributed are the results of that hashing function?
- What kind of input should I use to widen the distribution of hash result, to minimize chance of coincidental collision?
- What is the theoretical and practical limits on the number of applocks I can have active?
- What resources are used by applocks, such as amount of memory or limits on memory?

I am implementing a pessimistic locking mechanism for the rows of many tables for a special-needs app. As my applock key/name I plan to use a number representing each table combined with an ID number stored in each row. An example key/name might be something like `mydb_myschema_table0000000142_row0000241738`. I may have many of these active at a time, so I need to know about these limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't see official documentation answering your questions, but some of these things you can yourself (on a testing/dev server first!). Here's what I found:

Unless you are hoping to use a very large number of concurrent locks, you likely will not have any problems. On SQL Server 2017 CTP2.1, I was able to acquire `1MM concurrent locks` in about `26 seconds`. There were no collisions, and this appeared to use `~286MB of memory`.

The [SQL Server documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.110).aspx) specifies a maximum of 2,147,483,647 locks for 32 bit and "Limited only by memory" for 64 bit (which I assume you're using).

**Test script**

Below is a script that acquires 1MM locks and does basic monitoring of the elapsed time, memory consumed, collisions encountered.

```
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @result INT, 
    @i INT = 1,
    @locks_attempted INT = 1000000,
    @locks_acquired INT,
    @ts DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME();

WHILE (@i <= @locks_attempted)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Resource NVARCHAR(255) =
        'LongStringSoThatTheFirst32CharactersAreIdentical_' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR)
    EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = @Resource, @LockMode = 'Exclusive';
    IF (@result <> 0) THROW 50000, 'Failed to acquire lock', 0
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END

DECLARE @elapsed_ms INT = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @ts, SYSDATETIME());

SELECT @locks_acquired = COUNT(*)
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE request_session_id = @@SPID
    AND resource_type = 'APPLICATION';

-- Acquired 1000000 of 1000000 locks in 26351 milliseconds
RAISERROR('Acquired %i of %i locks in %i milliseconds', 0, 1,
    @locks_acquired, @locks_attempted, @elapsed_ms);

-- ~286MB of memory for OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
WHERE type = 'OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER';

ROLLBACK;
```

**What about collisions?**

I didn't observe collisions in any of my trials, but based on the documentation for [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql), it does appear that a 32 bit hash is used. With such a short hash, the odds of a collision [should be fairly high](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/) (see chart below). However, even with `10MM concurrent locks`, I did not achieve a collision. This might indicate that the hash is more complex under the hood, and that the `resource_description` column of `sys.dm_tran_locks` simply shows the first 32 bits of the hash (similar to the way it shows only the first 32 characters of the `@Resource` parameter). Or it might indicate that I was lucky.

If you are going to use this strategy, you should check to see if you get any collisions on your actual data. If you do, you could try to put unique elements (e.g., the `schema_id`, `object_id`, and your rowid) at the beginning of the `@Resource`. (It's not fully clear, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) suggests that the first 32 characters of `@Resource` might be combined with the hash in order to uniquely identify the lock.)

[image]

(Image from [Preshing on Programming](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/))

**Why do you want to do this?**

It seems unusual to use `sp_getapplock` so heavily for something that seems similar the type of row-level locking that SQL Server provides on its own. I'm assuming you've carefully considered other approaches, but if you haven't yet done so, you might want to think about other solutions that don't involve sp_getapplock.

Comment: As for, "why", I need to replicate the behavior of a simplistic database environment that supports only pessimistic row-based locking that survives transactions. Think of a box of index cards where one person at a time can hold a card. So definitely a special case, as noted in my Question. After much research I've concluded that the optimistic locking systems of MS SQL Server and Postgres are not able to support a simplistic pessimistic record-lock behavior directly. As a workaround, the explicit arbitrary locks (sp_applock here, Advisory Locks in Postgres) can be employed for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks so much for your excellent Answer. Good information that will help others in the future. Your chart is funny and informative. Can you cite the source?

Comment: @BasilBourque I cited it in the answer (though in a different paragraph, so I'll also add a citation right next to the chart). Here's the link: http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

Comment: @BasilBourque The locking I believe you're describing is equivalent to the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level that you can [set at a transaction level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763(v=sql.105).aspx).  If this is a test scenario, you should be able to set the isolation level for **all** transactions explicitly and take advantage of this without creating a custom locking routine.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Pessimistic locks live beyond the life of a transaction. So, no, Serializable is not a solution. Imagine a box of index cards in an office where any one person may claim a card as exclusively theirs for editing by applying a yellow stickie (a pessimistic lock). Any transaction is optional and orthogonal. The lock (the stickie) is held in place with or without a txn pending. A txn rollback undoes any edits but leaves the lock in place until the user (or app code) explicitly decides to remove the stickie/lock. If person goes on break, or on vacation, lock remains in place.

Comment: We have a hash collision using this function. The values that caused the collision: "5.14531731.0" hashes to "a56f30a2" as does "5.706010192.617831". 

SQL to duplicate collision:
EXEC \@result = sp_getapplock \@Resource = '5.14531731.0', \@LockMode = 'Exclusive', \@LockOwner = 'Session', \@LockTimeout = '0', \@DbPrincipal = 'public';

After doing that, this one fails:
EXEC \@result = sp_getapplock \@Resource = '5.706010192.617831', \@LockMode = 'Exclusive', \@LockOwner = 'Session', \@LockTimeout = '0', \@DbPrincipal = 'public';

Remove all backslashes

Comment: The comment "If person goes on break, or on vacation, lock remains in place" is not true in practice.
At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql#remarks) it says "Locks placed on a resource are associated with either the current transaction or the current session. Locks associated with the current transaction are released when the transaction commits or rolls back. Locks associated with the session are released when the session is logged out. When the server shuts down for any reason, all locks are released."